# ContentSelector WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, contenttemplateselector

I want to set a different content Template inside a button, to act like a Toggle Button, depending on the state of my ViewModel. I have simplified the code quite a bit, but in each Data Template the button's content draws different Path Geometries, together with a textblock.

ContentSelector class:

```
public class ContentSelector : DataTemplateSelector {
    public DataTemplate TrueTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate FalseTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container) {
        if ((bool)item)
            return TrueTemplate;
        return FalseTemplate;
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Added properties to the button to set its content, where 'State' isa  boolean value in my ViewModel, and the converter is just returning 'T' or 'F', based on the State of my ViewModel

XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
    <ContentPresenter>
        <ContentPresenter.Content>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                <Button  Content="{Binding State, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource ButtonContentConverter}}" Command="{Binding ToggleCommand}">>
                    <Button.ContentTemplateSelector>
                        <ContentSelector>
                            <local:ContentSelector.TrueTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="T" ... />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </local:ContentSelector.TrueTemplate>
                            <local:ContentSelector.FalseTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="F" ... />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </local:ContentSelector.FalseTemplate>
                        </ContentSelector>
                    </Button.ContentTemplateSelector>
                </Button>
            </DockPanel>
        </ContentPresenter.Content>
    </ContentPresenter>
</DataTemplate>
```

I cannot seem to hit the breakpoint in my ContentSelector class. It does work in the designer, meaning the button's content changes to 'T' or 'F' if I change it to return the corresponding DataTemplate in the ContentSelector Class, but when I run the application it never hits the ContentSelector, and the content of the button is completely empty.

Any ideas as to why this would happen? I have tried setting the Content of the button to the State of my ViewModel, and changing that to a boolean value using a converter, thinking that the content of the button must be set to trigger the ContentSelector, but it didnt work.

Comment: Can you show code you used to set the content of the button? Based on what you have here, ContentSelector's properties aren't set at all until the event is fired. Also, is there any reason you can't just do data binding to one property, and change toggle that one property between "T" and "F" when the event is fired?

Comment: I have added the properties where my content is bound to the State, but bear in mind its not just returning 'T' or 'F' for the content, that's just a placeholder for geometry paths I am drawing on the button as its content, depending on the State. Its just long/irrelevant to have all of that in the post. I have tried setting the content to fire the event, but its still never hitting my ContentSelector class